# DataSet upload to SQL server, foreign keys issue

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, dataset

Here is how I fill DataSet from server (calling this method for each table I need):

```
private static void PopulateDataTable(DataSet ds, string tablename, string sqlCommand = "SELECT * FROM {0}")
{
    var da
        = new SqlDataAdapter(String.Format(sqlCommand, "dbo." + tablename), connection);
    da.FillSchema(ds, SchemaType.Source, tablename);
    da.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
    da.Fill(ds, tablename);
}
```

After manipulating with data in DataSet tables I need to upload changes in tables back to server:

```
public static void UploadSqlServer(DataTable dt)
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", "dbo." + dt.TableName), 
        new SqlConnection(conn_string)))
    {
        using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
        {
             using (var cb = new SqlCommandBuilder(da))
                da.Update(dt);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that there are dependencies in tables (foreign keys) and I can't upload tables iterating them one by one (according to uploading order I can get an error `The INSERT (DELETE) statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint ...`)

What is the proper way to handle this?

Example:

`NamesList`: column1 (pm key) - `ID`, column2 - `name`

`People`: column1 (pm key) - `ID`, column2 (fn key in `NamesList`) - `name`

User added new row in `NameList` and created new person in `People` table. If I'll try to upload `People` table to SQL server first I get an error, cause there is no such `name` in `NamesList` yet. The situation is reversed with deletion.

Comment: What kind of manipulation are you doing? I am struggling to imagine the kind of generic manipulation you could be doing that means you can't control the order in which you are doing things.

Comment: Rows addition\deletion\editing, so some rows are marked as DataRowState.Deleted and so on.

Comment: So if you add rows to table A, and also rows to table B where there is a foreign key to table A, what is to stop you from committing the changes to table A before you commit the changes to table B, and avoid the conflict? You can handle deletes in table A by changing the referential trigger action of the foreign keys to `ON DELETE CASCADE`

Comment: The problem occurs in SQL server, not in local DataSet. This trigger (as I know) need to be changed in SQL base settings, but i don't have access to real database. I suppose, there is another correct way to store sql base locally in your app and upload it back to server rather than calling `UploadSqlServer` for each table in DataSet (I even can manually write correct order of calling this, but it differs for deleting and adding rows)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you specifying key values that does not exist in the parent table.

When you manipulate the data, are you adding new foreign key values to it?

If you are please check that the ones added does exist in the parent table.

Are you able to query the database to see if the foreign key values you have added do exist?

Comment: My local DataSet has all necessary rows, so there is no conflicts (I've checked this through DataSet viewer in VS). The problem occurs in SQL server. I've added an example in my question